# Alternative model to mod_rewrite maps

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to come up to an alternative to to mod_rewrite maps.

I need an engine that is capable of efficiently dealing with thousands of rewrite rules, also with "wildcards" or patterns, that can be controlled by an external program (something with a user interface to control it).  I am fairly confident that I could write such an engine as an external program with a combination of a c based frontend and a python backend communicating with unix sockets.

The problem I have is that apache will only start one instance of the program and the solution has to be able to scale to thousands of requests per second.  I'm worried that no matter how well I code the program that with a single instance and single thread it could become a bottle neck.

I've considered using dbm style maps, and they do seem to perform quite well, but there is no way to do anything with wild cards/regex etc.

Unfortunately apache is a requirement and I don't really want to go down the route of another process acting as a pass through.

All I can think of right now is writing a new module for apache but it seems a little excessive.

Another option would be to write a remap config on the fly and do an apache graceful but that feels a little dangerous.

Does anybody have any suggestions or thoughts?  Or know of a method of implementing DBM style maps with stored regexs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write an Apache module. It will be very fast and is not particularly complicated - you only need to implement a couple of the hook functions.